Can't click on the items under the Snackbar in jet pack compose
I can't click on the items under the Snackbar. I use Scaffold for showing snackbar, but Scaffold occupy all of the screen
   Box {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalProviderSnackbarImp provides snackbarImp
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize(),
            containerColor = Color.Black,
        ) {
            Box(Modifier.padding(it)) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}


Please have a look at the sample in the official documentation:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
    },
    floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            text = { Text("Show snackbar") },
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Image, contentDescription = "") },
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Snackbar")
                }
            }
        )
    }
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
    ) {
        Text(text = "HELLO WORLD")
    }
}

You need to provide a SnackbarHost to the snackbarHost parameter of the Scaffold Composable.
If you think that what you currently do is correct, then please show how you have implemented LocalProviderSnackbarImp.
